# gvim: Map a command which uses the current file name (%) in vimrc

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc

In gVim in windows, I want to map a command in the vimrc file that uses the current file (%). I write something like:

`map <F5> !mycommand %`

But then, when gVim first loads, it runs vimrc and says that it cannot find the current file, because it is not opened yet. 
How can I map this in the vimrc, but make it parse the % command only when I hit F5 (after I have opened a file)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
map <F5> !mycommand shellescape(expand('%'))<CR>
```

`shellescape()` makes the escapes the all the special character in the string (ex spaces)
`expand()` expands the string in this case the current file name.

However the map should have only been parsed when the map was executed. The might happen if you have an autocmd that runs `<F5>` or This might happen if you used `map` somewhere else and that got executed. It would be better to use the noremap versions of map unless you want recursive mappings.

Comment: The problem was I used a pipe when I shouldn't have, so it was executed anyway...